Simplesamlphp installation no input file specified
I am installing simplesamlphp with php-fpm and apache on a redhat server.
After the installation, I tring to go https://mywebsite.com/simplesaml I am being redirected to
https://mywebsite.com/simplesaml/module.php/core/frontpage_welcome.php and getting an error "No input file specified" . I think this should be an apache configuration issue (redirect maybe).
There is one rule for mod_rewrite for apache :
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php)$  fcgi://X.X.X.X/$1

I saw someone posted something similar and said he solved it using  cgi.fix_pathinfo=1 in php.ini file..Not working for me unfortunately. Any help is appreciated.Thanks
